# Counting authors with just one article

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (n2m) that contains authors' ids and their articles' ids. I'm counting number of authors who have just one article in the table. I'm using the following query:

```
select count(*) from authors_articles
where   AutID in
    (
     select AutID
     from authors_articles
     group by AutID
     having count(distinct articleID) = 1
    )
```

Now, I'm wondering if my query is correct and in any case can I improve this query to make it faster!?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query can be simplified to:

```
select count(*) from 
    (
     select AutID
     from authors_articles
     group by AutID
     having count(distinct articleID) = 1
    ) x
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be even simpler:

```
SELECT count(*) num_articles
FROM authors_articles
GROUP BY AutID
HAVING num_articles = 1
```

Comment: that's incorrect - num_articles will be the number of rows returned. OP needs number of rows returned with only 1 row in the aggregate (GROUP BY)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct.

MySQL happens to instantiate subqueries and to have inefficient methods for `group by`.  If you have an index on the `authors_articles(autId, articleId)`, then the following *might* perform better:

```
select count(*)
from authors_articles aa left outer join
     authors_articles aa1
     on aa.autId = aa1.autId and
        aa.articleId <> aa1.articleId
where aa1.autId is NULL;
```

This does a `left outer join` to match authors to any other article they might have written.  If there is none, then the author has one article, and the aggregation counts that.

This might work.  It might perform better, which under the right circumstances can be really, really important.  In general, though, I would stick with your query because I find it clearer on its intention.